# Command button to pop up msgbox if on 2 different column have same value

Tags: excel, vba

Help me guys..

I need some code in command button to check if on 2 different column have same value.. If same it will show a popup message..also if its not same, it will show a popup message..

Comment: _"I need some code..."_. I suppose you should get typing then! Welcome to SO - please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Afterwards, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Insert an ActiveX control command button from the developer tab. Then click view code. In between the header and End Sub do something like:

```
Dim totalRows As Long
Dim row As Long

totalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'this assumes your used range is the two columns height.

For row = 1 To totalRows

    If Cells(row, column1) = Cells(row, column2) Then

        MsgBox "row" & row & "has the same values"

    Else

        MsgBox "row" & row & "does not have the same values"

    End If

Next row
```

Obviously column1 and column2 should be the actual index of your columns.